# GRASP's Controllers and MVC's Controllers question

Tags: c#, java, model-view-controller, oop, controller

### Introduction to the problem

I have been taught about OO Analysis and Design through Craig Larman's [Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062), that follows the UP(Unified Process).

When using it, we usually draw a `Domain Model` and from it, doing Interaction/Association Diagrams, we get to the `Class Diagrams`. We generally then make `Controllers` that will be the "gate" between our `Model` and the "outside World" (following the GRASP patterns). All the world accesses to do any kind of logic has to go through the `Controllers`. I'll call those `Controllers` `Model's Controllers`, so later when we talk about `MVC's Controllers` we can differentiate them.
That can be depicted in the following most awesome diagram:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/pic1.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/pic1.jpg)

In black we have our `Model`'s objects and that classes' associations. In red we have the `Model Controllers`, that use data from the `Model`.

Basically, following this kind of design, you can only work with the `Model` through the so called `Model's Controllers` (we usually had one `Controller` per `Use Case`!).

### Now the question itself

When learning about the MVC, I always had the question of wherever the `MVC's Controller` was in fact `Model's Controller` or not? Are they the same concept or not? I think they are different concepts, as the `Model Controllers` we used to do didn't ever know about anything other than the classes on our `Model`, which is not what seems to happen in `MVC's Controllers`.

If what I'm saying is true, the following diagram should make sense:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/mvc_.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6187267/mvc_.png)

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand what you are talking about :)

What you are calling `Model Controllers` are known as Repositories. This is an interface that defines your specific interactions with the underlying model. For example, if you had a class representing Employees, and you wanted to do three things:

- `List<Employee> List()`
- `Add(int employeeID)`
- `Delete(int employeeID)`

Then you would define an interface called something like:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
{
    List<Employee> List();
    void Add(int employeeID);
    void Delete(int employeeID);
}
```

You would make sure that all your code deals with the Interface, and not the object directly - the Repository Pattern. This is what you are calling a `Model Controller`. See http://www.dev102.com/2008/12/08/working-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2-the-model-and-the-repository-pattern/ for more details, or search on Repository Pattern.

A contoller in the MVC world is actually something that dictates logic of program flow. For example, say you had a view of a list of employees. When the user hits "Delete" button on this view, the controller would load the appropriate repository and call the Delete method on it.

tl;dr: MVC Controller = When user does this, do this in a program (program logic); Repository (Model Controllers) = Define what interactions are supported with objects in my model

And yes, you're right :)